# Best way to not wait for a task to be completed

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await

Let's say we have an entity `Team` with fields `Id`, `Name`, `Points` and `CompetitionId`.

Based on this entity, I have a list saved in memory, with aggregate data for each team.

When I add some results, some lines in the table `Teams`, I want also to update this list, but not to wait for its result.

```
public async Task AddResults(List<Team> teams) {
  await context.AddRange(teams);

  await inMemoryService.SetRanking();
}
```

Inside of `SetRankings` method I get the teams lines from context and build the aggregate data. But I don't want to wait for that to be finished because is a long process (take ~ 10 minutes and will be increased each time). For that, I tried two methods:

1: to not use await keyword:

`_ = inMemoryService.SetRanking();` this works only because I'll not wait for the task to be completed. **BUT**, the new aggregated list from memory will be created on the another thread (I think), and when I'll try to get the data, I'll receive the old one.

2: using `ConfigureAwait` with false value:

`await inMemoryService.SetRanking().ConfigureAwait(false)` here, the request is still locked until this task is completed.

How can I solve this? thx

Comment: What type of application is this? ASP.NET Core? Console app? Win Forms? Something else? Is it .NET Framework? Or .NET Core or 5+?

Comment: Why does SetRanking take so long? That's a *long* time to run, especially for an in-memory service.

Comment: If you don't await your asynchronous methods, then you can't be sure they complete. That's not an appropriate solution. ConfigureAwait(false) doesn't do what you think it does, I suggest you [read up on it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/#what-does-configureawaitfalse-do). The proper solution if you want this process to continue on and the ranking aggregation process to run in the background while your original method continues on would be to use some sort of background process to execute the ranking aggregation logic. How you do that depends on the type of app it is.

Comment: is a .NET 7 rest api. I have 3 tables of ~ 25.000 lines, joining another 4 5 tables and I do some grouping by teamId, then a lot of `foreach` iterations and another groupings. I'm sure I can improve this, but is not the main problem

Comment: Okay, so ASP.NET Core has a [background service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) mechanism to host long running logic like that. Or it might make sense to publish a message to some sort of queue - then you can have a background service with ASP.NET Core (or better yet, a .NET Windows Service or AWS Lambda or Azure Function) listen for those queue messages and process them as they come in. Also check out [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) which gives a nice UI for handling background tasks.

Comment: hmm, I've worked with Azure WebJobs in the past, it looks something like this. I tought should be something simple. Next days I want to save this aggregate data in database and to set a job to build the data once per day. For now, I found something which works, but without knowing the disadvantages `_ = Task.Run(() => inMemoryData.SetRanking()).ConfigureAwait(false);` I need to read what you shared to me, thx

Comment: How do you know that the task completes successfully if you do that? Try this as an experiment: `Task.Run(() => { throw new Exception("test"); }).ConfigureAwait(false);`. You'll see that you don't get the exception bubbled up to you. If your aggregation process is silently failing, that could be a big problem for your app. The techniques I have told you about let you durably run things (when implemented properly) so that if they fail, you'll *know* they fail and be able to troubleshoot properly.

Comment: In this case, inside of `SetRanking` method I can use a `try catch`, where in catch I can log the error message in a database table. In an Admin Web app, I'll expect that this table to have 0 lines, else I'll execute the aggregate with a direct request (another endpoint) as admin

Answer (score 0):

The best way to not wait for a task to be completed is to give that task to another piece of code.

`AddResults` could add the work to a queue and return. Then, another piece of code processes that work.

The queue itself can be:

- and in-memory queue,
- a queue service that your chose cloud provider offers,
- even a database table.

The 'another piece of code' which monitors and processes the queue could be:

- a dedicated long running task in the same app
- another service (e.g [Azure Function with a queue trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-queue-triggered-function))